# SignalR IOS Client, Web Socket transport cannot invoke the method from server

Tags: c#, objective-c, websocket, signalr

I m using SignalR-ObjC Client to provide communication between my IOS application and .Net server.

I can connect with longpulling and invoke methods from self-host cross domain server without any error. But because of my applications needs i have to use WebSocket. I have a Singleton Manager like :

```
@implementation SignalRManager
static int reconnectingTry;
+ (id)sharedManager {
    static SignalRManager *sharedHttpManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedHttpManager = [[self alloc] init];
        sharedHttpManager.hubConnection = [SRHubConnection connectionWithURL:@"http://xxx:8080/signalr"];
        sharedHttpManager.proxy = [sharedHttpManager.hubConnection createHubProxy:@"myhub"];
    });

    return sharedHttpManager;
}
+(SRHubProxy *)proxy
{
    return [[SignalRManager sharedManager] proxy];
}

+(SRHubConnection *)connection
{
    return [[SignalRManager sharedManager] hubConnection];
}

+(void)start
{
    SRWebSocketTransport *transport = [[SRWebSocketTransport alloc] init];

    [[SignalRManager connection] start:transport];

}
+(void)stop
{
    [[SignalRManager connection] stop];
}
```

and i m invoking like :

```
 [[SignalRManager proxy] invoke:@"Hello" withArgs:[NSArray array]];
```

i establish connection and server can invoke client method but when i try invoke method from client to server the "Request failed:bad request(400)" error occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to be a problem with the protocol (SRClientTransportInterface) implementation in SRWebSocketTransport.

Actually is:

```
- (void)send:(id <SRConnectionInterface>)connection data:(NSString *)data completionHandler:(void (^)(id response, NSError *error))block;
```

and must be

```
- (void)send:(id <SRConnectionInterface>)connection data:(NSString *)data connectionData:(NSString *)connectionData completionHandler:(void (^)(id response, NSError *error))block;
```

Like subclass does not have that implementation is calling superclass (SRHttpBasedTransport) method and for that reason you got "Request failed:bad request(400)" (is another http request and not websocket).

To fix just open the file SRWebSocketTransport.m in your Pods project and change the implementation, something like this:

```
- (void)send:(id<SRConnectionInterface>)connection data:(NSString *)data connectionData:(NSString *)connectionData completionHandler:(void (^)(id response, NSError *error))block {
    [_webSocket send:data];

    if(block) {
        block(nil,nil);
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

pd: just checking github seems to be fixed in feature-2.0.0.beta1 branch

Comment: Great! That's solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dolcalmi Amazing! I wasted few hours on this, thanks! btw, why aren't we adding this to SignalR-ObjC base code?

Comment: How can i use pods to import feature-2.0.0.beta1 ?

Comment: that transport seems a whole lot flakier than long polling on some wifi networks with 8.x clients :-( I had to revert to longpolling :-[

Comment: @dolcalmi  I am not able to get data from SignalR server, Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477837/unable-to-receiving-data-from-signalr-server-in-ios